# How can I add libicp library in my catkin package?

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT:

I installed following package [link text](https://github.com/ylatif/rrr) as mentioned in instructions.
Now I want to use this package in my Cmakelist.txt so that I can use it in my program. I tried

```
find_package(RRR)
```

but it gives me error related to package config file.
I have series of .hpp files in my source directory.
I either want to convert them to a library file or add the whole package so that I can use them in my source files as headers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264264/how-can-i-add-libicp-library-in-my-catkin-package-?/) by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-21**:
Please do not use screenshots for what is essentially text. Could you please copy-paste the text from the terminal into your question directly? And then please use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-21**:\

> [..] as mentioned in the readme instruction file.

If referring to readmes/tutorials/websites/whatever, please include a link to those external resources, as we don't / can't know what you have been reading.

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2017-06-21**:
@gvdhoorn I updated my question. Can you please help ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-21**:
I only see this now:

> ```
> find_package(RRR)
> ```

perhaps something went wrong with copying the console text?

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2017-06-23**:
@gvdhoorn I couldnt replicate the behaviors most probably because of trying too many things. I will try to explain what I want to do.
I have a ros package named [RRR](https://github.com/ylatif/rrr) and I want to use this package's functionaluty in my code.

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2017-06-23**:
Since it is not a ros package I am unable to find and use it. Whats the way to go about it and sorry for bad formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest and simplest way to accomplish this to make a wrapper around libicp. You can follow catkin tutorials on creating a library file here (http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html)
After you have created this library you can just use add_library macro in your CMakelist.txt file. Now when you will add header files from libicp it wont create any issue.
If you need more help in it you can contact me at zainmehdi at koreatech.ac.kr

---

Originally posted by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) with karma: 225 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0